# What features does my server need for Apple push notifications?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing an app that makes use of the Apple Push Notification Service.

I'm looking for hosting of the server side. What features do I need to implement the service properly?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to build an Apple Push Notification provider server](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/) provides a great guide for getting started with APN.

Depending on how many APNs you need to send you may want to check out [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/). You can send up to 1 million messages a month for free with their service.

Comment: Thanks hipplar. I need more than one million of push so I have to buy / rent one for myself :)